Meaning of 意味s in this dialogue
I struggle to make sense of the below dialogue from Kokoro chapter 29:

「さきほど先生のいわれた、人間は誰でもいざという間際に悪人になるんだという意味ですね。あれはどういう意味ですか」
「意味といって、深い意味もありません。――つまり事実なんですよ。理屈じゃないんだ」
「事実で差支えありませんが、私の伺いたいのは、いざという間際という意味なんです。一体どんな場合を指すのですか」

I wonder if the first sentence can be understood as「さきほど先生のいわれたのは、人間は誰でもいざという間際に悪人になるんだという意味ですね」. I believe the narrator was trying to paraphrase what the Sensei told him earlier, so he ended with という意味ですね? I think 意味 here means something like 内容. In that case, 意味 in あれはどういう意味ですか simply means その内容の内容?
I am lost on what 意味 means in「私の伺いたいのは、いざという間際という意味なんです」. It seems to mean something like 事?

I think 意味 is just "meaning", it can be very ambiguous even in english. That's why she clarified what she wants to know which is「一体どんな場合を指すのですか」
